# How to change response header in middleware node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I searched a lot this question in google but unfortunately all solutions don't work for me.

I need to add special property to response header isAuth which has to be true. I tried out to use **set, setHeader, append** and so on. But all of these methods don't work for me

My middleware:

```
export const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('isAuth', true);
    next();
}
```

My controller, where I would like to read this header property isAuth:

```
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';

export const controller: RequestHandler = async (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs>, res:  Response<any>) => {
    const isAuth = res.header('isAuth');
    console.log('isAuth: ', isAuth)
};
```

in controller isAuth variable is not true, it is equal to

```
<ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    finish: [ [Function: bound resOnFinish], [Function: onevent] ],
    end: [Function: onevent]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: null,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: false,
  _headerSent: false,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 189
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 189
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
    _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 59763 },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 238,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  _header: null,
  _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: clearRequestTimeout] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 238,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    headers: {
      authorization: '5ac750e0-d2c6-4673-b022-4674f8c62df3',
      'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.10',
      accept: '*/*',
      'postman-token': '3e73d366-8e2e-493b-a01e-42ba2a7969ea',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content-length': '72'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'authorization',
      '5ac750e0-d2c6-4673-b022-4674f8c62df3',
      'User-Agent',
      'PostmanRuntime/7.26.10',
      'Accept',
      '*/*',
      'Postman-Token',
      '3e73d366-8e2e-493b-a01e-42ba2a7969ea',
      'Host',
      'localhost:3000',
      'Accept-Encoding',
      'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Connection',
      'keep-alive',
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length',
      '72'
    ],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a',
    method: 'POST',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 238,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _consuming: true,
    _dumped: false,
    next: [Function: next],
    baseUrl: '/group-workouts',
    originalUrl: '/group-workouts/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a',
    _parsedUrl: Url {
      protocol: null,
      slashes: null,
      auth: null,
      host: null,
      port: null,
      hostname: null,
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      pathname: '/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a',
      path: '/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a',
      href: '/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a',
      _raw: '/reserve/6093e5a0f876203e79de259a'
    },
    params: { id: '6093e5a0f876203e79de259a' },
    query: {},
    res: [Circular *2],
    body: {
      userId: '123',
      dateStart: '123',
      dateFinish: '123',
      cryptogram: '123',
      paymentDataId: '123'
    },
    _body: true,
    length: undefined,
    _startAt: [ 676465, 618613151 ],
    _startTime: 2021-05-07T13:12:18.733Z,
    _remoteAddress: '::1',
    route: Route { path: '/reserve/:id', stack: [Array], methods: [Object] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _startAt: undefined,
  _startTime: undefined,
  writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
  __onFinished: [Function: listener] { queue: [ [Function: logRequest] ] },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    '0': [ '0', 'i' ],
    '1': [ '1', 's' ],
    '2': [ '2', 'M' ],
    '3': [ '3', 't' ],
    '4': [ '4', 's' ],
    '5': [ '5', 'A' ],
    '6': [ '6', 'u' ],
    '7': [ '7', 't' ],
    '8': [ '8', 'h' ],
    'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' ],
    'x-dns-prefetch-control': [ 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control', 'off' ],
    'x-frame-options': [ 'X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN' ],
    'strict-transport-security': [
      'Strict-Transport-Security',
      'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains'
    ],
    'x-download-options': [ 'X-Download-Options', 'noopen' ],
    'x-content-type-options': [ 'X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff' ],
    'x-xss-protection': [ 'X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block' ]
  }
}
```

It is so strange.
Can anyone help me? I absolutely don't understand what's problem here.

Will be grateful for any help

Comment: Can't find `res.header()` anywhere in the express docs. Try using `res.get('isAuth')` while logging it out.  (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.get)

Comment: `res.header()` is an alias for `res.set()` - ie a setter for the response headers. It returns `this` - ie the response object it is called on - to allow methods chaining. The confusion may come from the fact that `req.header()`, on the other hand, is a getter for request headers. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you can do `res.locals.auth = true` , you can find more details in express documentation:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals